# Parallel Arrays with a textfile

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, parallel-processing

I want to organize a text file with multiple data

A  33    9.25

V  92    1.123

H 100    2.4

into a parallel Array

So far I got to declaring the arraylist and i know i need to do something with a while loop and hasnext... not sure where to go from there.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
        Scanner fileIn = new Scanner ( new File("sortdata.txt"));

      ArrayList<Character> array1 = new ArrayList<Character>();
      ArrayList<Integer> array2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      ArrayList<Double> array3 = new ArrayList<Double>();


        while (fileIn.hasNext())
        String i = fileIn.next();
        int k = 0;
        for(i.index(k);i.length();i.index(k++))
            if (i.index(k) =='.')
        {

        }

            }
```

I know some of my code is wrong but I've been looking at it for a long time, think i'm just missing something minor here.

Comment: `for(i.index(k);i.length();i.index(k++))`, What it means?

Answer (score 2):

After reading each line from the file here `String i = fileIn.next();`, `trim()` the String(to eliminate leading and trailing white spaces as suggested by [@X86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20088555/parallel-arrays-with-a-textfile/20088631#comment29929075_20088631)) and then follow the below steps.

1. Split the String on white space using the `String#split()` method.
2. The String[] returned by the split method above contains all the 3 data required.
3. From the string[0] get the character using `string.charAt(0)` and put it into the Character ArrayList.
4. Parse string[1] as a Integer using `Integer.parseInt(string[1])` and put it into the Integer ArrayList.
5. Parse string[2] as a Double using `Double.parseDouble(string[2])` and put it into the Double ArrayList.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to trim() it first??

Comment: @X86 - Nice suggestion. Incorporated it in the answer! :)

Comment: Thanks @R.J and @X86! My professor didn't really clarify on how to do this, seems pretty simple

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
while (fileIn.hasNextLine()) {
         String c[]= fileIn.nextLine().split(" ");
         array1.add(new Character(c[0].charAt(0)));
         array2.add(new Integer(c[1].trim()));
         array3.add(new Double(c[2].trim()));

         }
```

Comment: Instead of splitting based on " ", wouldnt it be better to use regex  with s+ ??

Comment: @X86 - Even better :)

Comment: @rohitjose Thank you! I see what you did there, really helped to simplify it